# Erlang error exception exit in ZeroMQ example

Tags: erlang, zeromq

i run **hwclient:main().** or  **hwserver:main().**
from zeromq example for erlang

https://github.com/zeromq/ezmq/blob/master/examples
from link 
[http://zeromq.org/bindings:erlang](http://zeromq.org/bindings%3aerlang)

and have error **"exception exit"**

```
crasher:
    initial call: ezmq:init/1     pid: <0.42.0>     registered_name: []
    exception exit: {noproc,
                        {gen_server,call,
                            [ezmq_link_sup,{start_child,[]},infinity]}}
      in function  gen_server:terminate/6 (gen_server.erl, line 746)
    ancestors: [<0.31.0>]    messages: []    links: []    dictionary: []    trap_exit: true    status: running    heap_size: 376    stack_size: 27    reductions: 174
  neighbours:

** exception exit: {{noproc,
                        {gen_server,call,
                            [ezmq_link_sup,{start_child,[]},infinity]}},
                    {gen_server,call,
                        [<0.42.0>,{connect,tcp,{127,0,0,1},5555,[]}]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/2 (gen_server.erl, line 182)
     in call from hwclient:main/0 (/examples/hwclient.erl, line 15)
```

what's wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing there isn't a process running on port `5555` that it is dependent upon (`connect,tcp,{127,0,0,1},5555`).  From [this](http://zeromq.github.io/erlzmq/) it looks like you need to start a server process first.

Comment: I start the server and immediately get the error described in the question

Comment: is there has this module `ezmq_link_sup`?